# can I iterate on collection coming from controller to view in section script and get data of it in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

```
    @model MVCTEST.Controllers.ViewModel
```

```
    var id = 2;
```

```
<div id="timezone">
    <a id="url">URL</a>
</div>
```

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        localStorage.setItem('timezone', 'cairo');
        var timezone = window.localStorage.getItem('timezone');

        // I need to iterate on collection (Model.IDs) in model which incoming from controller
        // and append every id to url, how can I do it?

        $('#url').attr('href', '../../Info/GetInfoDetails/@id?timezone=' + timezone);
    });
```

This code works fine, but when I try to iterate on collection I can't append every id in collection and append it to the url

Comment: Can you include your definition for `ViewModel.IDs` (`List<int>` or List<string>` etc) and include what you expect/would like the output to be, eg comma separated or just slapped all together eg (1,23,4 => 1234? seems useless).  If the `var id=2` is in your viewmodel, it won't be accessible from Razor - convert it to a public property.

Comment: Could be as simple as `'...Details/@string.Join(',', Model.IDs)?timezone.'...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to pass data from controller to view through ViewModel, and then access the data in JavaScript function, you can try to modify the code like below.

*pass data from controller to view*

```
var vm = new ViewModel
{
    IDs = new List<int> { 10, 12, 15 }
};
return View(vm);
```

*store data in a hidden field in view page*

```
<input id="hf_ids" type="hidden" value="@String.Join(",",Model.IDs)" />
```

access data in js function

```
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            localStorage.setItem('timezone', 'cairo');
            var timezone = window.localStorage.getItem('timezone');

            //access ids stored in hidden field
            var ids = $("#hf_ids").val().split(',');
            console.log("ids: ", ids);

            //generate url based on above ids
    });
    </script>
}
```

[image]